# Composition of integral operator continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $F:L^2(\mathbb{R}^D,\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb R$ be a functional of the form
$$
F(f) \triangleq \int_{\mathbb{R}^D} E(f(t))dm(t),
$$
where $E$ is a continuous function of $f(t)$.  Then let $g:L^2(\mathbb{R}^d,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^D,\mathbb{R})$ be a continuous map.

> Does it follow that the functional
> $$
> F^{\star}(g) \triangleq F(g(f)),
> $$
> is continuous in $g$?

Comment: $F : L^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $d=D$?

Comment: No in general I do not want $d=D$ unless needed.

Comment: Is $F : L^2(\mathbb R^D , \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes. Infact it is into $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Indeed your $F^*$ still does not make sense, you mixed up $d$ and $D$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I make left right errors from time to time